# Backup parleys videos

Tags: backup

I have Parleys Desktop installed on Fedora 13 and I want to format the disk. Can I make a backup of the videos I have installed so I can restore them after the format?  What do I need to copy? I don't know where the videos are stored; the application is in `/opt/ParleysDesktop/bin`

Comment: not a real question, for me

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about on linux, but on windows you find the videos on 
`C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\com.parleys.ParleysDesktop.XXXXX\Local Store\downloads\XXX\assets`